# Bookmark Sync, Sync's then removes bookmarks!

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I got bookmark sync to work (sort of), now it'll sync, then remove all bookmarks it had just synced?

Comment: Problem resolved it self, but I'm still curious as to why it was doing that?

Comment: Rob, could you post an answer saying that it's resolved itself and then accept it to that this question is marked as resolved? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably a bug in the extension
nice to have it solved yourself